# QProgressDialog/QMessageBox seem to inherit StyleSheets from my main window

Tags: qt

I'm openin a QMessageBox by using this static method:

```
reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "Save changes", "Save all modified files before exit?", QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);
```

I'm also later openin a QProgressDialog by using this:

```
QProgressDialog progress("Saving metadata to files...", "Abort", 0, queue.length()-1, this);
```

However, both seem to inherit the dark color (#333) from my main window. But the text is black so it's not visible.

I tried adding:

```
progress.setStyleSheet("color:#eee; background-color:#3a3a3a;");
```

But the window doesn't look fine as it looks borderless, etc.

Whats the proper way to set the stylesheet for the QProgressDialog and the QMessageBox I'm getting through the static method?

Is there a way to stop both from inheriting the stylesheet from the main window?

Comment: Don't pass `this` as the parent and the stylesheet won't be inherited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use selectors for example `QMainWindow {background-color: green}` where `QMainWindow` is the selector. This will prevent from inheriting unwanted style sheets.

Another example - to customize message box:

```
QMessageBox {background-color: red; color : white}
  QMessageBox QPushButton {min-width: 50; min-height: 19}
  QMessageBox QLabel {color: white}
```

You can place your stylesheets in the `.qss` file and read and apply globally at program start.

You can read more about using stylesheets in [The Style Sheet Syntax](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html)